# Check if a JavaScript 2D array is in ascending order?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an array as such

```
var arr = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,1]]
```

How do I check if the columns are in ascending order? 
For first column 1<4 returns true but the last column returns false as 3 is not less than 1.

The result should return an array of the columns that  returns false

Comment: What is the exact output you're looking for? Also please share your attempts.

Comment: So did you attempt something?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by first transposing the matrix (simply because its easier to deal with in js) and then map over each column (converting them from a set of numbers into a bool using `Array#every`).

```js
const arr = [ 
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,1]
];

const transpose = (arr) => Array(arr[0].length)
  .fill(0)
  .map((_, colIndex) => {
    return Array(arr.length)
      .fill(0)
      .map((_, rowIndex) => {
        return arr[rowIndex][colIndex];
      });
  });

const arr2 = transpose(arr);

const arr3 = arr2.map(col => {
  let previousValue = -Infinity;
  return col.every(v => {
    const tmp = previousValue < v;
    previousValue = v;
    return tmp;
  });
});

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the first inner array, and then check if you found some element on a particular column that is not in order using [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 1],
  [6, 7, 2]
];

let res = arr[0].map((n, cIdx) =>
{
    return !arr.some((inner, rIdx) => rIdx > 0 && inner[cIdx] < arr[rIdx - 1][cIdx]);
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the "columns" with the two values in descending order, you can use parallel arrays. Here is a succinct version of the code for that. (The second snippet is more verbose and provides further explanation.)

```js
    var arr = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,1] ], result = [];
    arr[0].forEach((n, i) => { // n is the number, i is the index
      if(arr[0][i] > arr[1][i]){ result.push(i); } // if descending, remember this index
    });
    console.log(result); // Logs `[2]` (an array with the index of the third column)
```

If you want to change which "column" the values are in so that they will be  in ascending order, you could do it like this. When you find a "misplaced" value, store it in a temporary variable to make room. Then you can assign the two values to their "correct" locations.

```js
const bigArr = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,1] ],
      a1 = bigArr[0],
      a2 = bigArr[1],
      resultArr = [],
      len = Math.min(a1.length, a2.length); // Uses min in case they have different lengths
for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
  if(a1[i] > a2[i]){ // Checks each position, and exchanges values if necessary
    exchangeValuesInParallelArrays(a1, a2, i);
    resultArr.push(i); // Adds this index to the results array
  }
}
console.log(bigArr); // Logs `[ [1,2,1], [4,5,3] ]`
console.log(resultArr) // Logs `[2]`


function exchangeValuesInParallelArrays(arr1, arr2, index){
  let tempStorage = arr1[index];
  arr1[index] = arr2[index];
  arr2[index] = tempStorage;
}
```